# Return value from element while showing another

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi lets say I'm showing a numeric value in an element **(not sure what element to use)**, what i want to achieve is once the numeric value is clicked **(Thinking of onclick="this.form.submit();" or submit button)** it will submit **different designated value** from the **numeric value** let us say. **Apple** then my sql query would retrieve apple and use it. **NOTE:** I have **multiple** numeric values and **multiple designated values for each numeric value** as an example it looks like this:

```
     (numeric value) = (designated value)
         15123       =  apple
         24151       =  orange
         39134       =  peach
```

Here so far is what i have.

```
 <input type='submit' name='searchthem' placeholder='<?php echo $numeric_value; ?>'
  value='apple'>
```

** NOTE i have multiple numeric values with different designated value

And this is the SQL in the same page:

```
    SELECT * from tbl_fruits where fruit_name='".$_POST['searchthem']."' ;
```

Would appreciate some help and ideas, If there is confusion please comment so i may further clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use select element and just submit the form so that it can process the values. if you wish to use AJAX, use some javascript and output the result in the browser.

Comment: Yes, but my design is on a table and i want to click just the numeric value to view the data from the database. but i will consider your idea if i am unable to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you should add an array for the definition terms and do it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="searchterm" value="<?php echo $numeric_value; ?>" />
<input type='submit' name='send' value="<?php echo $names[$numeric_value]; ?>" />
```

Then in PHP switch through the values:

```
switch($_POST['searchterm']){
  case(15123) $term = 'apple';break;
  case(24151) $term = 'ornage';break;
  case(39134) $term = 'peach';break;
}
```

This will secure your SQL query, too. [Beware: Never use unfiltered input (i.e. $_POST in your example) from the browser in SQL queries!]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you misunderstood the numeric value is just for show what is important is the value specified by the numeric value. So this is the whole process . . my system shows how many **items** have the color orange . . its shows the count of how many orange items, once i clicked the number the system would display complete information of all **item** that have the color orange.

Comment: ok, then i misunderstood. anyway if you want to display the number don't do it on the button itself, or if you want to do it on the button you need to filter out the number later (and sanitize the string for security reasons).